# In Java ExecutorService how to set max threads consumed by a request

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

Sometimes my server receives a request which can cause submission of 1000 tasks. While using a threadpool I don't want more than 15 threads from a threadpool to be consumed for the tasks from a same request.

If I don't do this it causes starvation for other requests.

Any suggestions on how to implement this.

Comment: Your question sounds a bit unclear. Usually one uses ExecutorService (essentially a thread pool) to avoid creating threads at run time; however, you are saying your task could create threads by its own. Are you using ForkJoinPool? Otherwise please tell us your use case.

Comment: Aggreed. I tried to clarify. No the request don't spawn new threads. They just sometimes generate too many tasks to be executed.

Comment: create a queue of `threadpoolexecutors` and every time check for availability

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases for creating too many requests:

1. Your system really need so many requests to be processed. If that's the case there is no way but to try to get better hardware and tune the performance of your individual tasks.
2. Your tasks can actually be conflated and merged (which I smell is the case for you). If this is the case, you can try a worker I got below where it guarantees only 1 execution is triggered as per many requests to put the task into the `ExecutorService`. The IDispatcher is essentially an `ExecutorService` of mine.

```css
/**
 * This class ensures the given task is only dispatched once in the dispatcher.
 * 
 * @author Alex Suo
 *
 */
public class DispatchOnceWorker implements IDispatchWorker {

    /** Logger of the class. */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DispatchOnceWorker.class);

    /** The key of task. */
    private final String key;

    /** The actual task to be dispatched. */
    private final Runnable taskWrapper;

    /** The dispatcher working on. */
    private final IDispatcher dispatcher;

    /** The counter for task scheduling count. */
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param key The dispatcher key for the task.
     * @param task The actual task to be executed/dispatched.
     * @param dispatcher The dispatcher working on.
     */
    public DispatchOnceWorker(final String key, final Runnable task, final IDispatcher dispatcher) {
        this.key = key;
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;

        this.taskWrapper = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    counter.set(1);
                    task.run();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.error("Error executing on dispatch key " + key, e);
                } finally {
                    if (counter.decrementAndGet() > 0) {
                        dispatcher.dispatch(key, this);
                    }
                }
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatch() {
        if (counter.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
            dispatcher.dispatch(key, taskWrapper);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should benchmark how many requests your application can handle concurrently so that the requests can be handled gracefully. In general, we use work queues for these kind of scenarios.

Snippet from the book "Java Concurrency in Practice":

```
Requests often arrive in bursts even when the average request rate is fairly stable. Queues can help smooth out transient bursts of tasks, but if tasks continue to arrive too quickly you will eventually have to throttle the arrival rate to avoid running out of memory.[4] Even before you run out of memory, response time will get progressively worse as the task queue grows
```

Having said that, In your case, probably, you can use  thread-per-request model or [threadpool-per-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11884327/dynamically-re-sizable-thread-pool) model.